# Как выполнять некоторый код каждые несколько секунд в PyQt5 не блокируя всю программу?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qgraphicsscene, qtimer

**Имеется:**

Недоделанная программа-игра, похожая на Duck Hunt. Имеются 4 линии форм: для начала и остановки игры, выбора режима скорости, результатов и самом низу расположено QGraphic-поле для будущих уток. При нажатии на кнопку `Начать игру` появляется 8 эллипсов (уток), при нажатии на которых они исчезают. При повторном нажатии на кнопку `Начать игру` старые эллипсы (утки) стираются и появляются новые.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема:**

Как можно реализовать "полет" данных эллипсов (уток) по всему полю, чтобы все остальные функции (нажатия на кнопки, нажатие на самих уток и т.п.) оставались активными? Уток можно перемещать с помощью функции `setPos` с применением случайных координат. Если использовать функцию `time.sleep()`, то вся программа виснет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать? Что-то слышал про потоки, но для меня это чёрный лес.

**Код:** (всё действие происходит в классе `FormBuilder`, а функция под реализацию движения помечена комментарием)

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QGroupBox, \
    QRadioButton, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem, \
    QGraphicsPixmapItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPainter, QColor, QPixmap, QIcon, QBrush, QPen

WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
WINDOW_WIDTH = 600
WINDOW_NAME = 'Истребитель уток'
WINDOW_ICON_NAME = 'Images\\main_logo.png'

MAIN_FONT = 'Times'
FONT_HEADER_SIZE = 13
FONT_BODY_SIZE = 8


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.draw_brush = QBrush(Qt.green)
        self.draw_pen = QPen(Qt.red)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.fill_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.task_label = QLabel()

        self.control_label = QLabel()
        self.start_button = QPushButton()
        self.quit_button = QPushButton()

        self.mode_label = QLabel()
        self.first_rbutton = QRadioButton()
        self.second_rbutton = QRadioButton()
        self.third_rbutton = QRadioButton()

        self.results_label = QLabel()
        self.play_time_qedit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Время игры")
        self.play_attempts_qedit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Число попыток")

        self.qgraphic_background_image = QPixmap("backimage.jpg")
        self.background_graph_scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.background_graph_scene.selectionChanged.connect(
            self.handle_qgraphic_selection)
        self.graphic_view = QGraphicsView(self.background_graph_scene)
        self.graphic_view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.graphic_view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.graphic_view.setFixedSize(565, 385)
        self.background_graph_scene.addPixmap(self.qgraphic_background_image)

    def fill_forms(self):
        self.task_label.setText("Задача: убейте всех уток за установленное время.")
        self.task_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.task_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.control_label.setText("Управление")
        self.start_button.setText("Начать игру")
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.build_qgraphic_ducks)
        self.quit_button.setText("Закончить игру")

        self.mode_label.setText("Режим:")
        self.mode_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.first_rbutton.setText("1-я скорость")
        self.first_rbutton.setChecked(True)
        self.second_rbutton.setText("2-я скорость")
        self.third_rbutton.setText("3-я скорость")

        self.results_label.setText("Результаты:")
        self.results_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.play_time_qedit.setDisabled(True)
        self.play_attempts_qedit.setDisabled(True)

    def create_layers(self):
        outline = '''
                    QGroupBox {
                        margin-top: 2ex;
                    }
                    QGroupBox::title {
                        subcontrol-origin: margin;
                        left: 3ex;
                    }
                    '''

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        task_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        task_layout.addWidget(self.task_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(task_layout)

        self.control_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.control_label.text())
        self.control_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        control_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.control_groupbox)
        control_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.start_button)
        control_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.quit_button)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.control_groupbox)

        self.mode_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.mode_label.text())
        self.mode_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        mode_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.mode_groupbox)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.first_rbutton)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.second_rbutton)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.third_rbutton)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.mode_groupbox)

        self.result_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.results_label.text())
        self.result_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        result_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.result_groupbox)
        result_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.play_time_qedit)
        result_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.play_attempts_qedit)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.result_groupbox)

        background_image_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        background_image_layout.addWidget(self.graphic_view)
        main_layout.addLayout(background_image_layout)

    def build_qgraphic_ducks(self):
        self.remove_qgraphic_ducks()
        for duck_number in range(8):
            ellipse = self.background_graph_scene.addEllipse(
                random.randint(5, 550), random.randint(5, 350), 30, 25, self.draw_pen, self.draw_brush)
            ellipse.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

    def remove_qgraphic_ducks(self):
        all_qgraphic_objects = self.background_graph_scene.items()
        for qgraphic_object in all_qgraphic_objects:
            if type(qgraphic_object) != QGraphicsPixmapItem:
                self.background_graph_scene.removeItem(qgraphic_object)

    def move_qgraphic_ducks(self): # реализация движения уток
        pass

    def handle_qgraphic_selection(self):
        all_qgraphic_objects = self.background_graph_scene.selectedItems()
        if len(all_qgraphic_objects) != 0:
            for qgraphic_object in all_qgraphic_objects:
                # ss[0].setPos(10, 10)
                self.background_graph_scene.removeItem(all_qgraphic_objects[0])


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_NAME)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(WINDOW_ICON_NAME))

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.main_grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        form_builder_object = FormBuilder()
        self.main_grid.addWidget(form_builder_object, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Фоновая картинка для QGraphic-поля:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QTimer.html)

Сделайте класс уток:

```py
class Duck(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
#...

# Количество уток
DUCKS_QTY = 8

class FormBuilder:
    # массив для уток
    ducks = []
    # таймер
    timer = QTimer()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        #...
        # Инициализация таймера
        self.timer.setInterval(100) # 100мс
        # Каждые 100мс будет вызываться метод timeStep
        # в котором вы можете перемещать ваших уток
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timeStep)

        # Останавливаем таймер
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.timer.stop)
    
    def build_qgraphic_ducks(self):
        for duck_number in range(DUCKS_QTY):
            duck = Duck()
            self.ducks.append(duck)
            self.background_graph_scene.addItem(duck);
        # запускаем таймер
        self.timer.start()

    # слот для таймера
    def timeStep(self):
        # Двигаем уток
        for duck in range(DUCKS_QTY):
            duck.setPos(<какая-то новая позиция>)
        # Обновляем сцену
        self.background_graph_scene.update()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: здравствуйте, у меня возникли проблемы с реализацией класса уток, точнее я вообще не знаю, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы превратить его в класс, который можно передавать в метод "addItem". Можете, пожалуйста, помочь?

Comment: @GunTHE наследовать от любого класса наследника QGraphicsItem, например QGraphicsPixmapItem

Comment: тааак, значит я нашёл проблему зависания и решил проблему с классом уток)

Comment: всё починил! Спасибо еще раз)